# how to center align div along with scroll bar

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

My requirement is to center align div and this div must have max and min height. if the content reaches max height it should show scroll bar.

Structure is also as seen below and also in jsFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AAMLA/185/

```
<div id="showHide" style="border:1px solid black;overflow: auto;min-height: 50px;max-   height: 72px;text-overflow: ellipsis;margin: 0 auto;font-weight: normal;display: inline-block;">

<div style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;margin:4px;">ABCDSEE</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;margin:4px;">ID</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;margin:4px;" >MS</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap;margin:4px;">TIMEOFATTACKffffffffffffffffffffff</div>

</div>
```

Now when i am using display: inline-block;" in the outer div scroll bar is coming but the div in not center align.

Also, If i am using display: table;" the div is centered align but there is no scroll bar.

So can any one please let me know what should i do to have the div center align and have scroll bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use this - `margin: 0 auto;` with the expected height and width instead of `inline-block`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AAMLA/187/)

Comment: yes that is ok, but what I want is to have div width as of text. Means that width should be as per text and when width of text exceeds 200px then ellipsis should be applied otherwise it should take width as per text.

Comment: @MananKapoor you need to use a parent DIV to align the inline element in center http://jsfiddle.net/AAMLA/188/

Comment: when i set width :200px it is taking that one but not of text. also using the new structure which u have send me i have set width in inner div but it is not taking width of text.